# Making a list of items with variables

Tags: c#

I want to create a system with a list of workouts for each user. So I made a class with a dictionary for each user and inside that class I want to add a list of workouts for exercise but its more than a list. I need a list of workouts with variables to set inside that workout like below.

```
User.GetWorkout("workout_1").Variable1 = "";
```

So Variable1 would be a string but what I want to know is how could I create a system like this? Is there a better way that a dictionary? Can someone link me too a good tutorial or explain a bit more about creating something like this?

User would be the user class for every user then GetWorkout would be a void witch gets the workout by the name given in the GetWorkout method

Variables I would like to add
a string called Name which would hold the workout name then something like a int for the level they need to achieve to unlock ths. I am looking to have the same amount of variables for all of them but all editable.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Are you suggesting that each workout would have a different set of properties?

Comment: All would have the same amount of variables but able to change each of them.

Comment: Do you have a specific question with your current implementation? Your question is incredibly hard to follow as written - it's unclear what your goal is.

Comment: To create some sort of list but with variables for each item on that list.

Comment: If GetWorkout gets workout it can't be void ...

Comment: +1 for the _"void witch"_. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you need but sounds like you need a `WorkOut` class:

```
public class WorkOut {
    public string Name;
    public int Level;
    ... other variables
}
```

and a list of workouts (or maybe a dictionary?) for a user:

```
List<Workout> workouts;
```

or

```
Dictionary<string, Workout> workouts;
```